# Can't figure out the usub in this integral.

Tags: calculus

1. $$\int_1^2 x \cdot \sqrt{x-1} dx$$

I can't figure out the usub here. If I do $u = x-1$, then $\frac{du}{dx} = 1$ and that seems to get me no where. Where do I go?

Comment: You could do a different one, but $u = x - 1$ will still work. You should be able to integrate $\int (u+1) \sqrt{u} du = \int u^{\frac{3}{2}} + u^{\frac{1}{2}} du$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $u$ substitution is fine. $x=1+u, dx=du$

$$\int_1^2 x \cdot \sqrt{x-1} dx$$

$$\int_0^1 (1+u) \cdot \sqrt{u} du$$
$$\int_0^1 \left(\sqrt{u}+ u \sqrt{u} \right)du$$

$$\int_0^1 \left(u^{1/2} + u^{3/2} \right)du$$

You can finish it easily.

Answer (score 2):

And by parts?:

$$\begin{cases}u=x,&u'=1\\v'=\sqrt{x-1},&v=\frac23(x-1)^{3/2}\end{cases}\implies $$

$$\int_1^2 x\sqrt{x-1}\,dx=\left.\frac23x(x-1)^{3/2}\right|_1^2-\frac23\int_1^2(x-1)^{3/2}dx=\frac43\left.-\frac4{15}(x-1)^{5/2}\right|_1^2=$$

$$=\frac43-\frac4{15}=\frac{16}{15}$$

Comment: There is something wrong with your result. The result of the integral is $16/15$

Comment: @TheNicouU Thanks. Nothing wrong with the integral, only a stupid typo in the very last line. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x-1=u^2 \implies dx=2udu$

$$\int_1^2 x \cdot \sqrt{x-1} dx=\int_0^1 (u^2+1) \cdot 2u^2 du$$

Comment: So I see your usub choice... how did you get to the (u^2 + 1) part?

Comment: Since $x-1=u^2 \implies x=u^2+1$

Comment: @Jwan622 Add one to the RHS of $x-1=u^2$ gives $x=u^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $$t=\sqrt{x-1}$$ then we get $$x=t^2+1$$ and $$dx=2tdt$$